# MySQL: How expensive is COUNT(DISTINCT) on indexed columns?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `bucket_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sub_bucket_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bucket_id`,`sub_bucket_id`,`id`),
  KEY `bucket_and_id` (`bucket_id`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

(IDs are distinct inside a sub bucket, but are not distinct across sub buckets within the same bucket.)

How expensive in terms of computation complexity it would be to run

```
> SELECT bucket_id, COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM t GROUP BY bucket_id
```

In particular, does it have better complexity then the full table scan or not?

On top of that, just to confirm: Will adding `WHERE bucket_id IN (1,2,3)` help so that no rows outside of the chosen buckets are scanned?

Comment: I don't understand the point of executing this query. It returns an array of 'counts'  with no way of establishing which 'count' belongs to which bucket_id !?! That said, a WHERE clause would improve things considerably - but you could test that for yourself as easily as ask us.

Comment: I just forgot to add a bucket ID to the query. Also, I am not inquiring if that would work or not, I want to know how this would scale as literally everything (i.e. number of buckets, number of sub buckets from each bucket and the size of each sub bucket) scales. Thank you, I have updated the post with more details.

Comment: I guess I just I don't know how to quantity the answer. It will be very expensive, but at the same time cheaper than the alternative of parsing the data set by hand. That said, if it was me, I'd just stick 1000 buckets in and see what happens.